# Laravel : is this eloquent or query builder join if im using model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Question 1 : is this eloquent or query builder ?

```
$q = Topic::from('topic')
    ->join( 'subject', 'subject.id', '=', 'topic.subject_id')
    ->select( 'topic.*',
        'subject.name as subject_name',
        )
    ->get();
```

Question 2 : if question 1 is eloquent, then is this the right query builder ?

```
    $q = DB::table('topic')
        ->join( 'subject', 'subject.id', '=', 'topic.subject_id')
        ->select( 'topic.*',
            'subject.name as subject_name',
            )
        ->get();
```

Question 3 : if in my Topic model, have a function to call topic image path, how do i access it with Query Builder from question 2 ?

is there a better way to access my topic image?

```
class Topic extends Model
{
    public function image()
    {
        //example
        return $pathImage;
    }
}
```

thanks if anyone can help me answer my question
im confused about the eloquent and query builder

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use the `from('topic')` in Eloquent, by calling Topic, eloquent gets the data from topic table, just use:

```
$q = Topic::join( 'subject', 'subject.id', '=', 'topic.subject_id')
    ->select( 'topic.*', 'subject.name')
    ->get();
```

Secondly, if the main table is called with the model as above code, in your blade foreach you can just use `$q->image()` to access whatever you are returning and you can't do that with your second approach which is a query builder.

A better approach would be to create a relationship between Topic and subject in your model, then you can just retrieve subjects like bellow:

```
$q = Topic::with('subject')->get();
```

If you don't know how to create relationships in the model, visit: **https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships**

Comment: sorry i need to ask 1 more, for performance in large table, using :

1. $q = Topic::with('subject')->get();

2. $q = DB:table('subject')->get(); 

is there any different in performance ? if there is 2 or 3 multiple join table to topic table like subject_table, user_table, subtopic_table ?

Comment: @StevenRz, In most cases DB facade is faster in performance, but Eloquent helps you write shorter code and it comes with many other functionalities out of the box. For example if you have 2 or 3 multiple joins you would need to write a few more lines of codes, while using eloquent you could just pass one more parameter to the select if you have the relationships established in your model, e.g. `->with('subject', 'user', 'subtopic')`.

Comment: I also removed the last part of my answer, because in join you could actually use the way you are using now, but if you would use select directly with eloquent, you would need to use DB::raw for raw sql syntax.

Comment: Lastly, it is just a matter of personal preferences and how you would like your app to run. Since eloquent has made querying database so easy for me, I personally enjoy using eloquent in most cases, although there will be times that I would go with DB if needed and even sometimes I would convert my results to Array for even better performance and faster calculations such as array_sum or filter, etc....

Comment: thanks for answering sir! you helped me understand laravel better,

sorry i dont know how to upvote in stackoverflow, this is second time i used stackoverflow